# How to get session value in ASP.NET boilerplate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session, aspnetboilerplate

I am working with an ASP.NET boilerplate **1.5.1** and I need to manage user sessions for some specific functionalities.

How can I set up sessions in an ASP.NET Boilerplate application?
Once set up, how can I retrieve and manage data within the session?
I have already tried `HttpContext.Current.Session` after setting up the config like this, `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />` but I'm getting the Session as NULL even after successful login.

Any help or guidance on this would be much appreciated!